# SQL - Flight Stops

Tags: sql

Can someone help me with this SQL problem? I'm having a hard time trying to understand how to create a query for this problem.

Given a table `flights`, find for each route (a combination of `origin` `destination`), the flight with the minimum cost or the minimum number of stops if the cost is equal.

```sql
create table flights(
  id serial primary key,
  origin char(3),
  destination char(3),
  cost int
);
```

Data example:

```sql
insert into flights (origin, destination, cost) VALUES
  ('SFO', 'JFK', 500),
  ('SFO', 'DFW', 200),
  ('SFO', 'MCO', 400),
  ('DFW', 'MCO', 100),
  ('DFW', 'JFK', 200),
  ('JFK', 'LHR', 1000);
```

Expected output:

```sql
/*
 origin | destination | stops | total_cost 
--------+-------------+-------+------------
 DFW    | JFK         |     0 |        200
 DFW    | LHR         |     1 |       1200
 DFW    | MCO         |     0 |        100
 JFK    | LHR         |     0 |       1000
 SFO    | DFW         |     0 |        200
 SFO    | JFK         |     1 |        400
 SFO    | LHR         |     2 |       1400
 SFO    | MCO         |     1 |        300
(8 rows)
*/
```

Comment: please post code and example data as text not as image

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

Edited

This query does what you asked for if you are using `PostgreSQL`. But maybe I was wrong thinking you were using `PostgreSQL` after the tags have been edited I see just `sql`. I hope this solution for PostgreSQL can help you anyway.

If you need any help on why and how it works please ask:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE all_routes (origin, destination, total_cost, stops) AS (
    SELECT origin, destination, cost, 0
    FROM flights
  UNION ALL
    SELECT f.origin, ar.destination, ar.total_cost + f.cost , 1 + ar.stops
    FROM flights f, all_routes ar
    WHERE f.destination = ar.origin
), min_fares_routes AS (
  SELECT origin, destination, min(total_cost) as total_cost
  FROM all_routes
  group by origin, destination
), min_fares_stops AS (
  SELECT mfr.origin, mfr.destination, mfr.total_cost,
    CASE
      WHEN mfr.total_cost = ar.total_cost
        THEN ar.stops
      ELSE
        NULL 
    END stops
  FROM min_fares_routes mfr JOIN all_routes ar 
  ON (ar.origin = mfr.origin AND ar.destination = mfr.destination )
)
SELECT origin, destination, min(stops) as stops, total_cost
FROM min_fares_stops
where stops IS NOT NULL
group by origin, destination, total_cost
order by origin, destination;
```

Comment: Can you explain `HOW` it works or share the tutorial. Curious to learn.

Comment: @Thirumal I'm sure that after reading postgrreSQL documentation on [WITH Queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) and the [CASE]() Conditional expression(https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html) you will get the most of it. If still in doubt. after reading it, I could answer to some specific question. I suggest paying attention to the explanation of the `Recursive Query Evaluation`.

Comment: Thanks @Giuseppe Schembri. I will check it.

Comment: @TML I think should work as it is,  just try it, [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-recursive-cte/) you can check the syntax for `WITH RECURSIVE` and [here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-function/) for `CASE`. Could you please deal with the suggestion have been given to you on the comments to your question?  It is very important, you should tag properly the question and get rid of the images and write it as text. Check [Code and Syntax Highlighting](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code) for Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Because you know what is the maximum number of jumps, you can write 3 select statements and use union/union all (because stops is always different union won't delete duplicates, so it's safe to use) to get data together. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

To get 0 stops you do select you have but put 0 as stops.

Second query gets flights with 1 stop, so you inner join fligts (f1) with flights (f2) on f1.destination = f2.origin and f2.destination <> f1.origin (so you don't come back to starting point, unless it's allowed then you don't need this <> comparison), set 1 as stops in this case, cost is f1.cost+f2.cost, origin is f1.origin, destination is f2.destination.

Then third query is similar to previous one but with another join with flight (f3) on f2.destination = f3.origin (and check if destination is not f1.origin like aboce), cost is f1.cost+f2.cost+f3.cost and 2 is steps, destination is f3.destination.

If you put this query inside `WITH options AS (...) SELECT * FROM options`, you can treat options like it was a table, do join with options to find the cheapest one with same origin and destination but lower price or equal price but less stops.
https://modern-sql.com/feature/with

You can test your select statements separately, to see that you get correct results with 1 and 2 stops.